# Android Call Filter working on my device, but not client's device

Tags: java, android, arrays, database, loops

I have created a simple call filter using a for loop that goes through a database and searches for a saved number. This filter works great on my device, but when I send it to my client, it automatically allows every call to go through. The filter is showing the "Deflecktur allowed a call from ...", so I know that we are getting to the if/else statement. For some reason it is just always going with the else statement on his device. Here is the code from the broadcast receiver.

```
if (blocker && isRunning) {
        String appName = context.getString(R.string.app_name);
        ITelephony telephonyService = getTeleService(context);
        if (telephonyService != null) {
            SparseArray<Phone> phones = getPhones(context, false);
            String incomingNumber = null;
            try {
                incomingNumber = intent.getExtras().getString(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
                if (incomingNumber != null && phones != null && phones.size() > 0) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "incoming call from " + incomingNumber);
                    boolean reject = false;
                    for (int i = 0; i < phones.size(); i++) {
                        Phone phone = phones.valueAt(i);
                        // Remove various characters to ensure a match
                        String matchNumber;
                        matchNumber = phone.getPhoneNumber().replaceAll("[^0-9\\+.,;#\\*N]", "");
                        if (incomingNumber.equals(matchNumber)) {
                            reject = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    if (reject) {
                        if (VERSION.SDK_INT < VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
                            // Old method of silencing the ringer
                            telephonyService.silenceRinger();
                        } else {
                            final AudioManager am = (AudioManager) context
                                    .getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
                            if (am.getRingerMode() != AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT) {
                                // Silence the ringer
                                if (mThread == null || !mThread.isAlive()) {
                                    mRingerMode = am.getRingerMode();
                                }
                                am.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
                                mThread = new Thread() {

                                    public void run() {
                                        SystemClock.sleep(3000);
                                        am.setRingerMode(mRingerMode);
                                    };
                                };
                                mThread.start();
                            }
                        }
                        telephonyService.endCall();
                        Toast.makeText(context, appName + " rejecting call from " + incomingNumber,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i(TAG, "call ended");
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, appName + " accepted call from " + incomingNumber,
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.i(TAG, "call accepted");
                    }
                } else {
                    // A phone state was encountered without incoming number, e.g. an outgoing call; ignore
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (incomingNumber == null)
                    incomingNumber = "[unknown]";
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e(TAG, "failed getting call info", e);
                Toast.makeText(
                        context, appName + " failed rejecting call from " + incomingNumber + "\n"
                                + e.getMessage(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The client is using a Samsung Galaxy Light, and I am using a OnePlus One

Comment: First of please know your client device os version and i think may some permission issue regards ITelephony may be happened.

Comment: Client is using a Samsung Galaxy Light, and I am using a OnePlus One

Comment: Please identify OS version and check there is something permission related issue.

Comment: Client is running android 4.2.2 and Im running android 4.4.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried adding a Log to see the values of matchNumber and incomingNumber to check they do in fact match? Could be a case of +61 4### vs 04###?

Perhaps you also need to strip the values of incomingNumber with the regex as well?

Comment: I have not tried a log because there was no error on my device. I know the numbers match on my device because the filter is working.

Comment: So, are you going to try a log then? Can you see what the client has entered in the filter ie, are you sure they're doing it right? Are you testing it from the same incomingNumber? Considering the main (only?) possibility is that incoming number doesn't match matchNumber, either it's reading the incoming number wrong from Telephony, the regex is not taking out a special character, or something else screwy is going on to stop them matching.

Comment: Well, I can log all i want, but without seeing the log from his device, it does me no good. He is three states away, so I have no simple way of logging.

Comment: I decided to create a toast that displays the incomingNumber = matchNumber and have the client take a screenshot. It worked well. I discovered that his device was reading the incoming number as 15555555555 and I was looking for 5555555555

Comment: Ah my bad, I saw a couple of the log messages and thought that when you said "The filter is showing the "Deflecktur allowed a call from ..."" it was on the log. Glad you got it sorted!